# is triangle a union of its sides or does it in addition contain its interior too?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am thinking what is a correct definition of a triangle. Is it more related to a concept of a circle or to a concept of a disc?

Wikipedia says that triangle is a polygon. Polygon is defined as a union of its sides.

However, there is an another definition of a triangle. It says that triangle is an intersection of three half planes in a certain settings, indicating the interior as a part of the definition too..

Comment: I tend to think of a triangle as a polygon, i.e. the union of three line segments (no interior). But I can see some contexts where we would want to speak of the *filled triangle* without having to always include that adjective. On some level, it doesn't matter. Just be clear what you mean in a given context.

Comment: In geometry it's usually defined as the union of its edges. But if there's another definition in a different text, that should take precedent.

Comment: As with all definitions, it depends on the context. How would you define the area of a triangle which consisted only of the union of its sides?

Comment: A triangle is also completly defined 1) by its vertices 2) as the set of points with all positive barycentric coordinates